# JQuery EasyUI Row Expander Detailed View Datagrid

Tags: jquery, datagrid, jquery-easyui

In the JQuery EasyUI data grid the default method to expand into the details view is clicking the plus sign in the first column. How can I make it so that clicking the row itself expands into the detailed view.

See below for default solution:

http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/datagrid/datagrid21.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the easyui plugin.. need to add the onclick event for the group row.

if this is the line in plugin,

```
_665.push("<div class=\"datagrid-group\" group-index="+i+" style=\"height:25px;overflow:hidden;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;\">");
```

add onclick event for the above as follows,

```
_665.push("<div onclick=\"groupHeadClicked('"+_668.fvalue+"')\" class=\"datagrid-group\" group-index="+i+" style=\"height:25px;overflow:hidden;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;\">");
```

so in your page, handle this groupHeadClicked method(do expand/collapse)..